# Cron job every minute, specify seconds offset

Tags: cron, cpanel

I configure the cron job in Cpanel, and it works when setting it to * * * * * , every minute.

However I dont want it to execute at the beginning of every minute, I want to specify an offset, like 7 seconds after the start of each minute.

I thought I would specify that by doing 
*/7 * * * *
But that doesn't work, I think it executes every 7th minute. There is no setting for "seconds" in cpanel. There is only "Minute     Hour    Day     Month   Weekday".
So, is it possible to configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this

```
* * * * * ( sleep 7 ; /path/to/executable param1 param2 )
```

Comment: Yes I just came to think of "sleep", to use the php function in my cron script. Is it more recommendable to add it in cpanel in the command field like you proposed, I thought I could addd "sleep(7) " in my script, or maybe it doesn't matter?

Comment: You dont need add it in your php code. Just use this approach which is quite native to cron and shell script

Comment: My command begins with "php -q" , do I add "sleep 7;" before php?

Comment: is it possible to send whole line?  `* * * * * ( sleep 7 ;php -q whateverScript.php )` if I understand correctly